# Incorrect checksum for freed object - error when printing

Tags: c++

I have made a class that's supposed to make a symmetric toeplitz matrix ([see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix)). The implementation of the class is shown here

```
class toeplitz{
private:
    int size;
    double* matrix;
public:
    toeplitz(const double* array, const int dim){
         size = dim;
         matrix = new double(size*size);
         for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
             for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
                 int index = std::abs(i - j);
                 matrix[i*size + j] = array[index];
             }
         }
    }

    ~toeplitz(){
        delete[] matrix;
    }

    void print() const{
        //loop over rows
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            //loop over colums
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
                double out = matrix[i*size + j];
                std::cout << std::setw(4) << out;
            }
        //start new line for each row
        std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }

};
```

I can't see what's wrong with this, but when I try and use this in a simple test function, I get malloc errors. The main function I have is

```
int main(){
    double array[] = {0,1,1,2};
    int len = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]);
    std::cout<<"length of array " << len << std::endl;
    toeplitz tp = toeplitz(array, len);
    tp.print();
}
```

It compiles and runs when I leave out the tp.print() line, but when I add this line I get error

```
test_toeplitz(8747,0x7fffdbee63c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fb119402788: 
incorrect checksum for 
freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6
```

I cannot figure out why this is. I've looked at the other questions about this on here but I can't tell how they relate to what I've done. As I understand it has to do with either double freeing memory or trying to modify memory after it's been freed, but I can't see where my code is doing that. Any insight into what's going on would be appreciated.

Comment: I should add, very occasionally it actually runs okay, and also sometimes it gives the error "segmentation fault: 11" instead

Comment: ***object was probably modified after being freed.*** I would look into that..

Comment: ***I should add, very occasionally it actually runs okay, and also sometimes it gives the error "segmentation fault: 11" instead*** This is a clear indication of Undefined Behavior.

Comment: This will cause you trouble: ***toeplitz tp = toeplitz(array, len);*** you didn't follow the rule of 3/5 with your class. As a result you will double delete your matrix.

Comment: I'm unaware of what exactly the rule of 3/5 is, could you explain or provide a link to explanation?

Comment: @bigbadpiano http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: Okay thanks, I guess what he's saying is that I should've defined a copy assignment and copy constructor since I have defined the destructor. It seems to work without anyway, even if it's bad coding practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You stumbled on the classical:

```
matrix = new double(size*size);
```

which allocates a double worth `size*size` when you wanted to do:

```
matrix = new double[size*size];
```

to allocate an array of the proper size. So you get undefined behaviour. Sometimes it works sometimes not depending on the memory configuration.

Since you're using C++, I suggest you use `std::vector<double>` or Eigen matrix template, and drop C arrays forever (no more memory leaks, no more failed allocations, possible boundary checking, only advantages)

Comment: Or even better a vector (yes yes I know the vector wont change size, but hey, it avoids manual memory management! and probably would have thrown an index out of bounds exception)

Comment: Using a vector doesn't guarantee boundary check with `[]` operator. You'll have to use `vector::at` to check for bounds. But agreed (and was editing my answer when you commented)

Comment: Yeah I know its not a guarantee, that's why I said probably. I *think* VS' implementation has asserts to that effect YMMV. ;) (Don't worry you already got my upboat)

Comment: I remember getting fed up by that and inherited from `vector` to add boundary checking to `[]` when a macro definition was enabled.

Comment: the compiler should definitely warn you (or provide a warn switch) about allocating 1 element using `new` on POD types. That would avoid this classical mistake that everyone has made once.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this did the trick. This is actually for a class on c++ and we are asked to dynamically allocate the array using new, but thanks for the heads up vectors

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you'll tell your teacher that C-arrays are _evil_.